# hide keyboard by dragging finger like sms app in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a chat feature in my app and I am trying to hide the keyboard by dragging the finger downward just like how you can hide the keyboard in the sms app in IOS 5.

I have subclassed UITableView, however as soon as scrolling starts I no longer get calls to

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I am wondering how I can get scrolling and find out where the finger is during scrolling so that if it starts to get close to the keyboard I can start to hide it.

I think this is a feature lots of people will want, any ideas on how to make it?

Comment: AFAIK if the table view doesn't take over the drag gesture, then all subsequent touch events are sent to the scroll view instead. So you need to implement this in a subclass of `UIScrollView`, or perhaps in a delegate of it.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, but wasn't sure how to replace the tableview's scroll viewer with my version

Comment: Sorry, you can disregard my previous comment. I had no idea `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. I've never seen a scroll view setup like that before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DAKeyboardControl](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl) it an MIT Licensed code source for what you are looking for.

Comment: @odyth, this is the answer you should want.  i was just looking to do this myself, and DAKeyboardControl is super easy to use.  one line of code (+ the #import), and it works like a charm.

Comment: This is very old and useless library now!

Answer (score 4):

Further googling revealed that this question is a duplicate of:

[How to move iPhone keyboard down like in Messages.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815888/how-to-move-iphone-keyboard-down-like-in-messages-app)

Answer (score 3):

I had enabled this feature in my app, with the help of [Daniel's DAKeyboardControl library](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl). You can implement the iMessage style keyboard hiding acidity with just one line of statement:

```
[self.view addKeyboardPanningWithActionHandler:^(CGRect keyboardFrameInView) {
    // Move interface objects accordingly
    // Animation block is handled for you
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, so you can detect the scroll position with UIScrollViewDelegate methods like `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Comment: how do you get the position of the user's finger though?

Comment: Create your own subclass of UITableView, implement the UIScrollView's  `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` method to detect the touch point, then monitor the movement in `scrollViewDidScroll:` to hide the keyboard or not.

Answer (score 2):

Luckly in iOS 7 Apple added the handy property `keyboardDismissMode` on `UIScrollView`. Now your app can behave like Messages just by changing a single property on your Storyboard, or by adding a single line of code.

This property uses the new `ScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode` enum. The possible values for the enum are as follows.

```
UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeNone
UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag
UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive
```

Here is the storyboard property do dismiss the keyboard on scroll