# How to move iPhone keyboard down like in Messages.app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iMessage Style Receding Keyboard in an iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780753/imessage-style-receding-keyboard-in-an-ios-app)

In the iOS5 Messages app, you can slide your finger down on the keyboard to bring it up and down. This is also done in the iA Writer app in the AppStore. How can I do this in code, that is, access and modify the Y position of the UIKeyboard?

Comment: This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780753/imessage-style-receding-keyboard-in-an-ios-app

Comment: yes, but it was answered better by CodaFi here.  @CodaFi, you should really copy your answer from here to the question this was closed in favor of, because the answer there might lead some astray as to how easy this is to solve with DAKeyboardControl (and perhaps the others, i haven't tried them).  Nothing can be as simple as one #import plus one line of code to do what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?  There are several open-source projects available that mimick the messages.app receding keyboard:

1. http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/madismissivetextview
2. http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dakeyboardcontrol
3. http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/imessagekeyboardeffect

To name a few.

Comment: After iOS7 release I haven't find good project to implement this stuff with iOS6/7 support.

Comment: After iOS 7 release this is not needed anymore because Apple has implemented it in the `UIScrollView`

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to do this, but you may be able to modify the keyboard's frame directly like this:

```
UIWindow* tempWindow;

//Because we cant get access to the UIKeyboard throught the SDK we will just use UIView. 
//UIKeyboard is a subclass of UIView anyways
UIView* keyboard;

//Check each window in our application
for(int c = 0; c < [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]; c ++)
{
    //Get a reference of the current window
    tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:c];

    //Get a reference of the current view 
    for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"(lessThen)UIKeyboard"] == YES)
        {
            //If we get to this point, then our UIView "keyboard" is referencing our keyboard.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use -isKindOfClass: instead of -hasPrefix?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII because isKindOfClass will only tell you if it is a UIView, and ALL objects returned by tempWindow.subviews are UIView Objects.

Comment: @mohabitar I'm not sure if its app store legal, but I know there is no official way to do it, so if other non-apple apps got away with it, theres a decent chance you will too.

Comment: @Patrick no, I meant to use it with the [UIKeyboard class] as the variable, or even NSClassFromString.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something? I don't have access to any UIKeyboard object.

Comment: @mohabitar Back in the days when the decimal numberpad didn't exist, I used something like this to add an extra button to the keyboard. My app was approved.